# How do I set up an IPv6 DMZ with iptables without a static allocation?

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, ipv6, openwrt

I have several networks which are on Comcast's residential network.  I need to access those networks from a variety of environments, via an SSH proxy on one of the hosts.

(As it happens I'm using OpenWRT, so a specific solution there would be helpful; but I'm also generally curious how one does this with any Linux or BSD-based edge routing solution.)

With IPv4, this is relatively straightforward: since all my internal IPs are allocated with DHCP, I can simply set up a forwarding rule to move port 22 on the external interface to port 22 on a specific IP.

Since my IPv6 addresses are all allocated with SLAAC, I don't have a static address that I can use in ip6tables-land to forward things.

How can I detect changes to the prefix allocation so that I can establish new iptables rules? Or is there a way to set up a rule which forwards to a particular host based on discovering its IP address from its MAC address or something like that?  (These hosts are all on a single segment so multicast and such should work.)

Comment: You really should be using DHCPv6, and preferably Barrier Breaker.

Comment: Why should I be using DHCPv6? Why Barrier Breaker (by which I assume you mean the OpenWRT version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you can use [Dynamic prefix forwarding](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/fw3_configurations/fw3_ipv6_examples#dynamic_prefix_forwarding), my example of rule in `/etc/config/firewall`:

```
config rule
    option name 'HTTP-SSH-IPv6-myserver01'
    option src 'wan'
    option proto 'tcp'
    option dest 'lan'
    option dest_ip '::2c18:81a2:3422:f690/-64'
    option dest_port '22 80 443'
    option family 'ipv6'
    option target 'ACCEPT'
```

which creates iptables rule(s) like this:

```
-A zone_wan_forward -d ::2c18:81a2:3422:f690/::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "!fw3: HTTP-IPv6-myserver01" -j zone_lan_dest_ACCEPT
```

Here is also described the same case: [Dynamic IPv6 Subnet & ip6tables](http://blog.dupondje.be/?p=17).

So it is even more easy than IPv4 — you don't need to configure static IP-addresses at your DHCP server.

P.S.: "DMZ" in title confused me at the first reading of question.

Answer (score 1):

SLAAC allocated addresses are static (except for temporary address) as long as the prefix is static, and the router knows the prefix.

You have serveral choices:

- You could open port 22 to all addresses, then you would be able the ssh to all the hosts.
- Configure the DHCP client on the router to call a script which changes the ip6tables rules.
- Use the u32 match to match on part of IP address.
- If the internal interface of the router is a Linux software bridge use ebtables, which can match on TCP ports and Ethernet addresses.

Comment: First and foremost - the whole point here is that the prefix is not, or rather may not be, static.  And I definitely don't want SSH accessible on all hosts :-).  Also, the router is getting its prefix via router advertisements, not DHCP, so that wouldn't help.  I can't find a radvd hook for "prefix changed".  Can ebtables inspect IP-level packet information?  My impression was that it was all about ethernet-layer stuff.  Finally: what's a "u32 match"?

Comment: No, your router is obtaining the LAN prefix via DHCP (that's how Comcast distribute them) and advertising it using router advertisements.

Comment: That's interesting; I do have a dhcp6 client running, which I wasn't aware of.  I don't see any log messages pertaining to getting a prefix though… so it sounds like the best option would be to add the DHCP client configuration. Could you expand your answer to include some specifics on that?  (Particularly I find writing rules to fit in with OpenWRT's somewhat complex existing firewall tricky.)